# Are there 3 or 12 MTG FNM cards for 2018?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Usually FNM issues 12 cards per year. For 2018 we see [only 3 cards in that year](https://scryfall.com/sets/f18). Is Scryfall not up to date or has WotC stopped the FNM series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 12, only the 3 double sided tokens were numbered for FNM 2018 the other 9 used their set collector number.

In 2018, Wizards started giving out double sided tokens as FNM promos, this was not a popular decision, so after the first three of those tokens they changed the system. They started giving out versions of cards from the current sets. They had a different frame, promo rarity "P" and the "FNM" name on their collector number line, which had the collector number matching regular pack pulls. [Opt](https://scryfall.com/card/prm/68047/opt) was the first one:

[image: Opt]

The rest were: [Cast Down](https://scryfall.com/card/pdom/81/cast-down), [Shanna, Sisay's Legacy](https://scryfall.com/card/pdom/204/shanna-sisays-legacy), [Elvish Rejuvenator](https://scryfall.com/card/pm19/180/elvish-rejuvenator), [Militia Bugler](https://scryfall.com/card/pm19/29/militia-bugler), [Murder](https://scryfall.com/card/pm19/110/murder), [Conclave Tribunal](https://scryfall.com/card/pgrn/6/conclave-tribunal), [Sinister Sabotage](https://scryfall.com/card/pgrn/54/sinister-sabotage), and [Thought Erasure](https://scryfall.com/card/pgrn/206/thought-erasure). To find all 12 you can use [this query on scryfall](https://scryfall.com/search?q=%28is%3AFNM+year%3A2018%29+OR+set%3AF18&order=released&dir=asc).

Now, however, they have stopped making specifically FNM promos and instead are having packs of promos using this frame that can be given out by stores how the stores want to.  These promos are marked with the set they are from and numbered as alt art promos are currently, with a just a number higher than the set count, and that count is excluded, They have the rarity "P" and "Promo Pack" for where they came from. At the moment, FNM prizes are digital for MtG Arena, where FNM events are currently played, this may change once the pandemic ends and we get back to playing in store events again.

Comment: The FNM list for 2019 is: Growth Spiral, Light Up the Stage, Mortify, Augur of Bolas, Paradise Druid, Dovin's Veto, Corpse Knight, Negate, Disfigure, Flame Sweep, Thrashing Brontodon, Glass Casket, Improbable Alliance, Inspiring Veteran, Kenrith's Transformation, Slaying fire

Comment: Some further references: [FNM Promo cards](https://scryfall.com/search?q=is%3Afnm&order=released), [Promo pack cards](https://scryfall.com/search?q=is%3Apromopack&unique=cards&as=grid&order=released), and [Promo pack cards that are just the inverted frame originals, not including the planeswlaker stamped reprints](https://scryfall.com/search?q=is%3Apromopack+not%3Apromostamped&unique=cards&as=grid&order=released).